# "ReferenceError: "sheet" is not defined.

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I get this error when trying to run my code. It points to line 71 specifically, for the data variable.

```
function MAIN_createBatchMarketReports () { 
var marketReportDataSheet = getdataSheet(MARKET_REPORT_TEMPLATE_FILE_NAME); 
var currentDataColumn = INIT_DATA_COL;

var lastCol = marketReportDataSheet.getDataRange().getLastColumn();

var data = sheet.getRange(AGENT_NAME_ROW,currentDataColumn,1,lastCol).getValues()[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    if (data[i] != "" && data[i] != undefined) {
      createMarketReport(marketReportDataSheet, i+1);
    }

  }
}
```

Full script: http://pastebin.com/n70iLPsA

Any help in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: the initial question was resolved by david yes! thanks for the follow up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a mistake, you have to replace sheet to marketReportDataSheet.
The variable sheet is define inside the function getdataSheet not in the function MAIN_createBatchMarketReports

```
function MAIN_createBatchMarketReports () { 
var marketReportDataSheet = getdataSheet(MARKET_REPORT_TEMPLATE_FILE_NAME); 
var currentDataColumn = INIT_DATA_COL;

var lastCol = marketReportDataSheet.getDataRange().getLastColumn();

var data = marketReportDataSheet.getRange(AGENT_NAME_ROW,currentDataColumn,1,lastCol).getValues()[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    if (data[i] != "" && data[i] != undefined) {
      createMarketReport(marketReportDataSheet, i+1);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. 

I did that however it turned an error on line 120 where I initiate the email to be sent. 

    Invalid email: Seller's (line 120, file "Code")